# Spring Session Redis Data is not clearing index to sessions in Redis

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I am using Spring Session Redis Data (configured with autoconfiguration, no customizations so far) which defaults to using `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` as the `SessionRepository` implementation.

However, sometimes in Redis (after sessions have already expired but no logout is performed), key with prefix of `spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:` persists with a TTL of -1, meaning Redis won't expire the key.

Why isn't Spring Session (Redis Data) cleaning this key up when sessions expire? I can't find mention in the documentation either.

I've stored attribute with the principal's name to the session as described in the documentation, but that doesn't solve this issue. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/api.html#api-findbyindexnamesessionrepository for details.

Redis version used: 6.2.6 (docker image of bitnami/redis:6.2.6)

Relevant Dependencies:

- Spring Boot 2.6.2
- Spring Security 5.6.1
- Spring Session Core 2.5.0
- Spring Session Data Redis 2.5.0
- Spring Data Redis 2.6.0

The reason why I wouldn't want the index to persist is that if there are many users who have logged in at least once and having a key persisted to Redis which acts like index, then Redis would have to store data that may not be accessed for long time (or at all).

Comment: It looks like you are running into [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1791), which was fixed in Spring Session 2.6.x. Try upgrading to the latest version of Spring Session.

Comment: Hi @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana! Thanks for pointing out to that issue.
This solves the problem!
Could you make an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Thanks for pointing this out. I had this problem since day one at my job but my predecessor applied a bandage solution to trigger a scheduled job to delete them to clear the memory build up in Redis. But now the bandage can be ripped off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1791) in Spring Session version 2.5.3 and prior.

If you update to Spring Session 2.5.4 or any 2.6.x, the issue is fixed.